# Get data from a remote server using WSDL

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

My remote server expose some methods in WSDL. Is it possible to use this WSDL within jasper server to get data? I looked into examples that Jasper consume data that are available in the XML but didn't found anything on using web service (WSDL).

Thanks